# Getting raw html through HTTP GET request using Socket's

Tags: c#, sockets

I am getting nothing when try to do it this way:

```
    var ips = Dns.GetHostEntry("stackoverflow.com");
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sock.Connect(ips.AddressList[0], 443);

    var buffer = new byte[4096];

    string h = "GET /tags HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: stackoverflow.com\r\n" + "\r\n";
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(h);
    sock.Send(buffer);
    var recbuffer = new byte[4096];
    var rec = sock.Receive(recbuffer);

    string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recbuffer, 0, rec);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are connecting to port 443, https, you must use a SSLStream

Comment: receive buffer is filled with zeros so I get "" in response

Comment: @Gusman thanks. Now I am getting "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet forma" when trying to use SSLStream (AuthenticateAsClient)

Comment: Check which protocol you have specified, the server may not support it.

Comment: Take a look at [SslProtocols Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework)). There's an example of a connection using port 443 and security protocols.